# Ubuntu won't load after clearing orphaned inode

Tags: boot

I have tried pulling the plug and googling but I don't know what to do.

What happens is at boot time I see

```
Recovering journal
Clearing orphaned inode
```

Then it makes the notification sound, then hangs at

```
/dev/sda8: clean**********/************* blocks
```

Loaded desktop after 15 mins for 1 second, I hit login, then it went back to the text screen :(

Comment: Orphaned inodes implies there was an unclean shutdown. What were you doing before this happened? You can [edit] your question with more detail. At the moment there is not enough info to help you

Comment: since you solved your problem, you should post an answer to it as an answer rather than editing your question - that will be more helpful to other people :)

Comment: @Zanna im not allowed to post answers cause of my rep on these forms how people downvote when i ask for help :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*OPs answer in question moved into CW answer*

I fixed my problem. I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> to go to terminal mode and purged the nvidia driver, because the system was trying to load a driver I had removed and Ubuntu loads all drivers before user login.

So Ubuntu forgot to remove something in the driver update after I deleted it (probably the initramfs needed to be regenerated)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was not able to loing grphically, I just logged in minimal (ctrl+alt+F1) and ran "sudo apt-get -f update" & "sudo apt autoremove" then reboot the system.

There was some broken packages preventing the booting process. Working now!!