# Ubuntu does not boot anyloger, hangs at clearing orphaed inode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have Ubuntu 22.04

I have not made any specific changes, but Ubuntu suddenly hangs at boot with following logs:

> /dev/sdb3: recovering journal
>
> /dev/sdb3: Clearing orphaned inode 1313213
>
> ...
>
> /dev/sdb3: clean XXX/YYY files. ZZZ/AAA blocks

and then hangs forever.

Seems like someone had a similar error at [Ubuntu won't load after clearing orphaned inode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/822867/ubuntu-wont-load-after-clearing-orphaned-inode), but slution did not work for me, because CTRL+ALT+F1 is not doing anything for me. Also ctrl+alt+ent won't trigger a restart.

I could boot from USB to a demo-Ubuntu, if this helps.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Can you check your hard drive from a livesession and also try t fix filesystem from in there?

Comment: @nobody yes I did run it from livesession and run fsck. Found some orpheans and fixed it, now the orpheans errors don't appear anymore, but it still shows /dev/sdb3: clean XXX/YYY files. ZZZ/AAA blocks and hangs

Comment: check your harddrive with smartmontools.